# Message Box OwnerShip setting

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I am a noobie to WPF, I have created a chat application and now I need to show message boxes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMGWa.png) but what is my issue is when the user clicks out of my application, application goes to the background but opened popup is open on the foreground like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Ocl.gif)

code used is::

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailId))
 {
    BusyIndication = Visibility.Hidden;
    CustomMessageBox.Show("Email ID should not be empty", "Email ID", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    LoginView.SignInButton.IsEnabled = true;
 }
```

I think that I need to set ownership property but don't know how to do it.

Any suggestion??

Comment: Your `CustomMessageBox` is not owned (`Show(this)`). What type is `CustomMessageBox`? In any case, specify the Owner (the Window it belongs to).

Comment: Please, share how `CustomMessageBox` looks like

Comment: CustomMessageBox is a NuGet Package [in this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFCustomMessageBox/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your pick:

```
Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText);
Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption);
Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button);
Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon);
Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult);
Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult, MessageBoxOptions options);
```

Comment: but these are related to normal system generated message box class with no added functionalities above-mentioned custom message box is a featured message box with following methods::
`
Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText);
Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption);`

with owner parameter

Comment: I was under the impression that "CustomMessageBox" was a class you had made that inherited from MessageBox.


Even then the "above-mentioned custom message box is a featured message box with following methods:: ` Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText);"

You state that it still accepts "Window owner" as a parameter which should change it's owner...
I don't know exactly how your CustomMessageBox.Show() function works, but you should be able to specify the Window owner in the parameters somewhere...
Perhaps use of the "base" keyword will help here.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, as you mentioned I have mentioned parent window object as the owner, even though its functionality is not altered it still stays on top